# How can I use When step after a Then step in specflow?

Tags: specflow

I'd like using specflow for a system test
Test steps whould be like:

```
When I'm selecting "A"
Then "A" item(s) appear
When I'm selecting "B"
Then "A" and "B" item(s) appear
When I'm unselecting "A"
Then "A" item(s) appear
```

Problem is that 2'nd When is considered as a new method by the specflow.
Did anyone of you know what's the solution for that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be fine. Please can you post the `When` step method you are using, as it's probably related to the regex. Usually I find that using single quotes in your step definitions makes the regexes easier to work with

Answer (score 1):

your scenario has strange use of language for me. It implies that you are in the process of doing something, rather then performing and completing and action. I think the `When I select 'A'` would read better.

Anyway these step definitions should allow your steps to be reused:

```
[When(@"I'm selecting ""(.*)""")]
public void WhenIMSelecting(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[Then(@"""(.*)"" item\(s\) appear")]
public void ThenItemSAppear(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[Then(@"""(.*)"" and ""(.*)"" item\(s\) appear")]
public void ThenAndItemSAppear(string p0, string p1)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[When(@"I'm unselecting ""(.*)""")]
public void WhenIMUnselecting(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

Generally I prefer single quotes to wrap the parameters as it makes the regexes easier to work with, so I would rewrite the scenarios like this:

```
When I select 'A'
Then 'A' item(s) are shown
When I select 'B'
Then 'A' and 'B' item(s) are shown
When I deselect 'A'
Then 'A' item(s) are shown
```

Which would result in these step definitions:

```
[When(@"I select '(.*)'")]
public void WhenISelect(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[Then(@"'(.*)' item\(s\) are shown")]
public void ThenItemSAreShown(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[Then(@"'(.*)' and '(.*)' item\(s\) are shown")]
public void ThenAndItemSAreShown(string p0, string p1)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}

[When(@"I deselect '(.*)'")]
public void WhenIDeselect(string p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

But obviously its your domain so use whatever language you want in your scenarios :-)